# Bootstrap Doesn't Work for Opera Phone Simulator

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, simulation

I am designing with Opera Mobile Simulator, and am using bootstrap to design, but the drop down navigation doesn't work.

I do not know if the problem is with the simulator or with bootstrap.

I would appreciate all help... Thanks. Here are the codes for the menu

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <div class="container">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="brand">School Portal</a>
                <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav">
                        <li><a href="index.php">Dashboard</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="javascript()" class='dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown'>Students <b class="caret"></b></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="register.php?t=student">Register Student</a></li>
                                <li><a href="view.php?t=<?php echo md5("student"); ?>">All Students</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="javascript()" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Teachers <b class="caret"></b></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="register.php?t=teacher">Register Teacher</a></li>
                                <li><a href="view.php?t=<?php echo md5("teacher"); ?>">All Teachers</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>                
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Code samples or it didn't happen.

Comment: Could you put it in a JS fiddle? It would be much easier to find the issue if its in JSFiddle. Thanks.